# getDefaultPeopleDetector() of HOGDescriptor returns null vector in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

Here I am trying to detect the people in a video frame. I am using HOGDescriptor and SVM. But getDefaultPeopleDetector() returns a null vector. I am unable to figure out why? So, if someone could suggest a solution.
Here is the code:

```
    int main()
       {
         VideoCapture cap(0);
         if(!cap.isOpened())
            {
               cout<<"Cannot open Camera";
               system("pause");
               return -1;
            } 
         cout<<"Camera Open";
         cvNamedWindow("rahul",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
         HOGDescriptor hog;
         static vector <float>    detector=HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector();
        if(!detector.size());
          {
            cout<<"No detector";
            system("pause");
             return -1;
           }
         hog.setSVMDetector(detector);

         while(1)
          {
            Mat frame;
            bool status=cap.read(frame);
            if(!status)
             {
               cout<<"cannot read frame";
                 break;
              }

            vector<Rect> found, found_filtered;
             hog.detectMultiScale(frame, found, 0, Size(8,8), Size(32,32), 1.05, 2);
            size_t i, j;
            for (i=0; i<found.size(); i++) 
              {
                  Rect r = found[i];
                  for (j=0; j<found.size(); j++) 
                      if (j!=i && (r & found[j]) == r)
                         break;
                      if (j== found.size())
                      found_filtered.push_back(r);
                }

             for (i=0; i<found_filtered.size(); i++) 
                  {
                     Rect r = found_filtered[i];
                     r.x += cvRound(r.width*0.1);
                     r.width = cvRound(r.width*0.8);
                     r.y += cvRound(r.height*0.07);
                     r.height = cvRound(r.height*0.8);
                     rectangle(frame, r.tl(), r.br(), Scalar(0,255,0), 3);        
                   } 

              imshow("rahul",frame);
              if(waitKey(30)==27)
                 {
                    cout<<"escape";
                    break;
                  }
          }



       return 0;
     }
```

I always get "No detector" at the output according to my code i.e the detector.size() is null.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of solved this problem.So if someone ends up with this problem can try this.

First check whether hog.cpp is present in objdetect/src.It was present in my case.
If it is present, then include hog.cpp in the code with full path to the file.

When I included this file, it gave another error in precomp.hpp (which is included in hog.hpp ). The error was cvconfig.h was not found. I checked the folder and it didnt have cvconfig.h .

So, I commentted the line #include "cvconfig.h" in precomp.hpp and then on everything worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I think u just need fix

```
static vector <float>    detector=HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector();
```

by

```
static vector <float>    detector=HOGDescriptor::hog.getDefaultPeopleDetector();
```